# Find object in a python list using the 'in' operator

Tags: python, list, keyword

Is it possible to do something that looks like this:

```
if obj in a_list_of_the_same_obj_type:
     #do stuff
```

My obj already have the `__eq__` and `__ne__` function that compare on an attribute so I thought the `in` keyword would call it but it doesn't look like it does.

Comment: Hint: `__contains__`

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: I did a little experiment and `__eq__` is definitely used by `in` for lists. The problem might be with your implementations of `__eq__` and `__ne__`.

Comment: membership tests requires ``__hash__`` not ``__eq__``.  The test usually reads "this obj is in this sequence" rather than "The sequence contains an object equal to mine", hence the membership test is mostly practical for immutable objects.

Comment: @Meitham you need to hash for sets, dicts, etc. List membership is based in identity followed by equality.

Comment: As @morsecodist mentioned, `__eq__` is definitely used and my `__eq__` implementation was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, operator 'in' calls the `__contains__()` of python´s built-in list object which then calls the `__eq__()` of your object, so make sure that the `__eq__()` dunder method in your obj-class is properly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) to be able to test for membership

Comment: The question makes it seem like he's using a `list` of objects, not a custom type.

Comment: agreed. The `in` is being invoked on the list and therefore it is the list that has it's `__contains__` method invoked. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I partially agree, but OP said that `__eq__` is implemented already. If this is list of custom classes and goal is to test membership of the same class - `__eq__` if definitely enough for this. If this does not work, I assume that `a_list_of_the_same_obj_type` isn't supporting iteration protocol.

Comment: @Slam This is the answer ;) I just used it.